# Does the "Official Meteor for Windows Preview" support mobile packages?

Tags: windows, mobile, meteor

Does meteor for windows support mobile packages?
I have tried running the Linux version through vagrant but couldn't run android emulator.

Answer (score 2):

As of Dec 2014:

No, it doesn't. And there are no plans to work on mobile support on Windows in the near future.